# python list convert to list with unique on subsequences

Tags: python-3.x, list, unique, python-itertools

I have a list that looks like this:

```
["A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","A","A","C","C,"B","B","A"]
```

A I want to run unique on all sub-sequences , so the output will be:

```
["A","B","A","C","B","A"]
```

What is the best way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: See the [`unique_justseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) inside a list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = ["A","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","C","C","B","B","A"]
>>> [k for k, _ in groupby(lst)]
['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```

Another functional approach using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = ["A","A","A","A","B","B","B","A","A","C","C","B","B","A"]
>>> list(map(itemgetter(0), groupby(lst)))
['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a convoluted one-liner, you can do it with a list comprehension:

```py
>>> l = ["a", "b", "a", "a", "x", "x", "a", "a", "a"]
>>> x = [l[x] for x in range(len(l)) if x == 0 or l[x - 1] != l[x]]
['a', 'b', 'a', 'x', 'a']
```

Here's another idea using `reduce` from [functools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html). I think it's an overkill, but maybe it can help you work it into something better:

```py
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> r = lambda x,y: x+y if x[-1] != y else x  ## reduce function
>>> reduce(r, l)  ## you could write in lambda directly
'abaxa'
>>> list(reduce(r,l))
['a', 'b', 'a', 'x', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sublists are sorted as in the question you could do something like:

```
unique_list = []
unique_list.append(your_list[0])
for literal in your_list
    if not unique_list[-1] is literal
        unique_list.append(literal)
```

However, this will not be a very fast solution an there are probably better ways to do it.